# ReactJS Multiple arrow function

Tags: reactjs

```
.then((myJson) => this.setState({example: myJson},() => this.toggleModal()));
```

I´m fetching data from my API and then i toogle my Modal to display some data, but i need to execute `this.example()` function before the modal get displayed, i´ve tried to make;

```
.then((myJson) => this.setState({example: myJson},() => this.example() ,() => this.toggleModal()));
```

But this way `toogleModal()` is not executed! 
How can i solve this?

Comment: nope not like this`() => this.example() ,() => this.toggleModal()` ;like this: `() => { this.example(); this.toggleModal() }`   setState only takes 1 callback function.  this will just create a single arrow function around your functions..

Answer (score 0):

Like @Developer said, try it:

```
.then((myJson) => this.setState({example: myJson},() => {
      this.example();
      this.toggleModal();
 }));
```